# How to redirect only blog posts from root to directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

My old site had a blog with permalink structure like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/blog-post-url
```

There are many posts all over the web that used these URLs.

But now I've moved my blog posts to its own directory, with the permalink structure like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/blog/blog-post-url
```

So what I need to do is redirect all old blog links from `/blog-post-url` to `/blog/blog-post-url` **but redirect only blog post** as I have other pages with URLs like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/page-urls
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin [simple 301 redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) to redirect your old pages to new one's, you can also use wildcards to re-direct multiple pages